# Calculo Consumo Interfaces Mediante SNMP

Tags: php, linux, bash, php5

Estoy intentando guardar en una base de datos los valores de IfinOctets y IfOutOctets para tener un registro del consumo de ancho de banda por clientes. Sin embargo los valores no me coinciden, he visto muchas formulas diversas y ninguna me da valores aproximados o similares a los que me muestra cacti en sus graficas de consumo. Por el momento tengo algo así

Lo voy a detallar mucho:

```
$host="172.16.2.37";
    $snmpwalk_eth = shell_exec("snmpwalk -v1 -c public '".$host."' interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr | grep -e \"eth0\"");
    $snmpwalk_ath = shell_exec("snmpwalk -v1 -c public '".$host."' interfaces.ifTable.ifEntry.ifDescr | grep -e \"ath0\"");
    $eth = substr($snmpwalk_eth,16,1);
    $ath = substr($snmpwalk_ath,16,1);
    //echo "eth $eth \n";
    //echo "ath $ath \n";
    $interface_eth=$eth;
    $interface_ath=$ath;
    if(($eth or $ath) != "") {
        $interval="5";
        $print_awk="'{print $4}'";
        //eth
        $oid_in_eth = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.$eth";
        $oid_out_eth = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$eth";
        $oid_ifspeed_eth=".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.$eth";
        //wlan
        $oid_in_ath = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.$ath";
        $oid_out_ath = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.16.$ath";
        $oid_ifspeed_ath = ".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5.$ath";

        echo "Host : $host \n";
        $tasa = "8000000";
        //$ifspeed_eth=shell_exec('snmpget -v1 -c public '.$host.' '.$oid_ifspeed_eth.' | awk '.$print_awk.'');
        //$ifspeed_ath=shell_exec('snmpget -v1 -c public '.$host.' '.$oid_ifspeed_eth.' | awk '.$print_awk.'');
        //$eth=shell_exec('snmpget -v1 -c public '.$host.' '.$oid_in_eth.' '.$oid_out_eth.' | awk '.$print_awk.'');  

        $result = shell_exec('snmpget -v1 -c public '.$host.' '.$oid_in_eth.' '.$oid_out_eth.' '.$oid_ifspeed_eth.'| awk '.$print_awk.'');
        $out = explode("\n",$result);   
        //var_dump($out);
        echo "IN : $out[0] \n";
        echo "OUT : $out[1] \n";
        echo "Speed: $out[2] \n";
        sleep($interval);
        $result2 = shell_exec('snmpget -v1 -c public '.$host.' '.$oid_in_eth.' '.$oid_out_eth.' '.$oid_ifspeed_eth.'| awk '.$print_awk.'');
        $out2 = explode("\n",$result2); 
        //var_dump($out);
        echo "IN_2 : $out2[0] \n";
        echo "OUT_2 : $out2[1] \n";
        echo "Speed_2: $out2[2] \n";

        Echo "Calcular .... \n";
        //Calculo eth IN  
        $suma = ($out[0]+$out[1]);
        $suma2 = ($out2[0]+$out2[1]);
        $total=($suma2-$suma);
        $bytes = ($total/$interval);
        $bit=($bytes*8);
        $velocidad=($bit*1024);

        echo "LAN bits por segundo IN $bit  \n";
        echo "LAN Mbps por segundo IN $velocidad \n";
```

No se si la formula que estoy usando es correcta, pero algo no anda bien pues no cuadran los valores. Si alguien lo ha hecho o tiene alguna idea de como hacerlo, se agradeceria.